# Excel Macro VBA autofill

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a simple macro where it would populate a vlookup formula and I want to drag down the formula on the whole sheet. It is giving me a static value depending on the current spreadsheet row count. I want others to use the same macro and not have to change the row and columns in the code.

```
ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("O2"), Sheets("CD").Range("B:H"), 7, False)
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E1525")
    Range("E2:E1525").Select
```

What should I do where the range isn't static because not everyone who uses this macro has 1525 rows on their sheet. So if someone has 1600 rows on their sheet macro does not work. Does that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

If the formula will always be in column E, try this:

```vb
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CD")

'determines last row for each user's sheet
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row 'use 5 for Column E

Dim searchValue As String
searchValue = ActiveSheet.Range("O2").Value

'Sets Vlookup, then copies for whole range desired
ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(searchValue, targetSheet.Range("B:H"), 7, False)
Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Select 'Replace ActiveSheet with the sheet name if it is a different sheet
```

I don't have a great way to test this right now, but let me know if any errors appear

Comment: Few errors i have been seeing with this code. It is not doing VLOOKUP properly. It is only copying the number from col O2 and then incrementing it until 388.
2nd its not dragging the formula all the way down it is stopping at line 388 and I have definitely more than 388 lines.

Comment: Likely need to determine the last row based on some other column than E.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Formulas

```vb
Sub CopyFormulas()

    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = dws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("E2", dws.Cells(lCell.Row, "E"))

    Dim Formula As String: Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(O2,CD!B:H,7,FALSE),"""")"
    
    drg.Formula = Formula
    
    MsgBox "Copied formulas to """ & drg.Address(0, 0) & """.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```